# A question of connectedness of subspace

Tags: general-topology

My question is about Lemma 23.1 in James Munkres' topology. Suppose $X$ is a topology and $Y\subset X$. Suppose we found two (specific) sets $A$ and $B$ that are  disjoint, non-empty, and their union is $Y$. If $A$ and $B$ are CONNECTED and $\overline{A}\cap B\not=\emptyset$ ($\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$ in $X$), can we conclude that $Y$ is CONNECTED? What causes problem for me here is that the sets $A$ and $B$ are specific and not general.

Comment: Perhaps (at least) $B$ is not meant to be open? Because as it is both $A,B$ are clopen and thus $\overline{A}=A$.

Comment: You are right, I corrected!

Comment: @Chrystomath I understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Consider a continuous function $f : Y \rightarrow \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$. Because $A$ and $B$ are connected subsets of $Y$, $f$ must be constant over $A$ and $B$. But because $\overline{A} \cap B \neq \emptyset$, then by continuity $f$ must take the *same* value over $A$ and $B$. That means that $f$ is constant over $A \cup B$, so $f$ is constant over $Y$. So $Y$ is connected.

Comment: With the same argument one may prove that $(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ is connected, which is not. The $f$ must be the same on each of these intervals as on their respective closure and the closures intersect so $f$ must be the same constant everywhere?!

Comment: @M.Rahmat How may you ? The closure of $(0,1)$ is $[0,1]$ which does not intersect $(1,2)$. Indeed, the argument is the following : let's say that $f=\varepsilon_A$ over $A$ and $f=\varepsilon_B$ over $B$. Then take $x \in B \cap \overline{A}$ : you have $f(x)=\varepsilon_B$ because $x \in B$, and by continuity, $f$ must be equal to $\varepsilon_B$ in a small neighbourhood of $x$. But every neighbourhood of $x$ intersect $A$, so $f$ takes the value $\varepsilon_A$ on a neighbourhood of $x$, so $\varepsilon_A = \varepsilon_B$. Is is more clear ?

Comment: . @ TheSilverDoe. I am fine thanks.